# How to create multiple rows from single row with time interval in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've a table with start_date, end_date and frequency. Using MySQL query I want to generate multiple rows with every date between start_date and end_date. Here are the tables:

```
ID | start_date |  end_date  | frequency
----------------------------------------
 1 | 1402876800 | 1403049600 | daily
```

Now I want the query output as following:

```
active_date | start_date |  end_date  | frequency
--------------------------------------------------
 1402876800 | 1402876800 | 1403049600 | daily
 1402963200 | 1402876800 | 1403049600 | daily
 1403049600 | 1402876800 | 1403049600 | daily
```

All dates are in timestamp value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: anyway to do with only 1 table?

Comment: Didn't get any. But by using procedure, it's hopefully achievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a date table and join on it using a between condition, eg,

```
SELECT d.date AS active_date, t.start_date, t.end_date, t.frequency
FROM {your_table} AS t
INNER JOIN {date_lookup_table} AS d
ON d.date BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date
```

You could also use a procedure to calculate this... But in my experience having a date lookup table is pretty helpful in general, especially if you do things like add month and year to it. And it's definitely a lot simpler to use and to troubleshoot. If it were me, I'd add a date lookup table, make sure it's got an index on date, and move on.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But what will be the structure for date_lookup_table? As this table contains the year value, do I need to run cron job for upcoming dates?

Comment: If it were me, I'd create a table with datetime, date {yyyy-mm-dd}, month {1, 2, 3, etc}, quarter {1, 2, etc}, year {1970, 1971, etc}.  Instead of a cron job, I'd just generate it all in Excel and go from 1970 to (say) 2100. Import it to MySQL. Add an index to every column. It'd take about 10 minutes to create that table, import it to SQL, and add the columns. And at least in my experience that kind of table gets a lot of reuse, especially if you do any kind of business reporting with your data.